# scatterplot3d package; how do you re-size a regression plane

Tags: r, 3d, scatter3d

I am interested in generating a series of simple 3d scatterplots which include regression planes without interactions using the scatterplot3d function in R.  The following code generates almost what I am after with one problem- in many cases the regression plane extends outside of the bounding box (e.g. in this case, the corner nearest x, y and z =0).  I tried changing the axis limits to increase the box size, but this does not alter the axis ranges as specified (which, according to the package documentation is an unfixed bug).  Is there a way to either 1) re-draw the box to include the entire plane or 2) shrink the plane to include only the portion within the box?

## example data

```
bugs<-c(335.20,8.68,1.94,3.22,21.79,11.16,1618.00,108.76,250.59,400.81,233.86,15.05,274.62,419.21)
max_dq<-c(0.015,0.001,0.001,0.001,0.002,0.007,0.04,0.001,0.014,0.003,0.002,0.006,0.004,0.013)
since_dist<-c(21,58,5,1,1,19,42,33,22,300,240,79,327,42)

library(scatterplot3d)
```

## 3 d plot

`reg_plt<-scatterplot3d(max_dq,since_dist,bugs,angle=50)`

## regression plane

`reg_plt$plane3d(lm(bugs~max_dq+since_dist))`

Comment: Does it have to be `scatterplot3d`? `rgl` may be an alternative for your problem: `library(rgl); fit <- lm(bugs ~ max_dq + since_dist); plot3d(max_dq, since_dist, bugs); planes3d(coef(fit)["max_dq"], coef(fit)["since_dist"], -1, coef(fit)["(Intercept)"], alpha=0.5)`.

Comment: @lukeA: Thanks very much.  I was able to generate a reasonable plot using rgl.

Comment: If anyone can answer my question regarding scatterplot3d, however, I would still be most interested.